Default Route Excluding VLAN on HP switch
I have configured HPE 5710 Layer 3 switch with multiple vlans. The Default Static Route displays it's interface as Vlan10, I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 from addresses in that vlan, including the switch management IP. However I am unable to ping 8.8.8.8 from addresses in vlan120. The default static route next hop (10.1.1.1) is the IP address of another switch with a trunk port configured between the two. I am able to ping across to this switch from vlan120, it is only the default static route that is not working for vlan120.
Here is the routing table on the switch:
Destinations : 17       Routes : 17
Destination/Mask   Proto   Pre Cost        NextHop         Interface
0.0.0.0/0          Static  60  0           10.1.1.1        Vlan10
0.0.0.0/32         Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
10.1.1.0/24        Direct  0   0           10.1.1.90       Vlan10
10.1.1.0/32        Direct  0   0           10.1.1.90       Vlan10
10.1.1.90/32       Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
10.1.1.255/32      Direct  0   0           10.1.1.90       Vlan10
10.1.2.0/24        Direct  0   0           10.1.2.2        Vlan120
10.1.2.0/32        Direct  0   0           10.1.2.2        Vlan120
10.1.2.2/32        Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
10.1.2.255/32      Direct  0   0           10.1.2.2        Vlan120
127.0.0.0/8        Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
127.0.0.0/32       Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
127.0.0.1/32       Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
127.255.255.255/32 Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
224.0.0.0/4        Direct  0   0           0.0.0.0         NULL0
224.0.0.0/24       Direct  0   0           0.0.0.0         NULL0
255.255.255.255/32 Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0

And here is the verbose output for the default static route I have configured:
Destination: 0.0.0.0/0
   Protocol: Static
 Process ID: 0
  SubProtID: 0x1                    Age: 77d15h46m06s
       Cost: 0               Preference: 60
      IpPre: N/A             QosLocalID: N/A
        Tag: 0                    State: Active Adv
  OrigTblID: 0x0                OrigVrf: default-vrf
    TableID: 0x2                 OrigAs: 0
      NibID: 0x11000000          LastAs: 0
     AttrID: 0xffffffff        Neighbor: 0.0.0.0
      Flags: 0x10060        OrigNextHop: 10.1.1.1
      Label: NULL           RealNextHop: 10.1.1.1
    BkLabel: NULL             BkNextHop: N/A
  Tunnel ID: Invalid          Interface: Vlan-interface10
BkTunnel ID: Invalid        BkInterface: N/A
   FtnIndex: 0x0           TrafficIndex: N/A
  Connector: N/A                 PathID: 0x0

To clarify I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 from 10.1.1.90 but I am unable to ping 8.8.8.8 from 10.1.2.2. However I am able to ping 10.1.1.1 from both.
Can someone clarify whether that default static route is only configured for traffic in vlan10 and how I can allow other vlans to use that route?
Many Thanks,
Chris

Unless you filter traffic between 10.1.2.0/24 and 10.1.1.0/24 that should work. Most likely, your default route does work - but the back route (or WAN access/NAT) fails. You can run a packet trace to verify whether the echo request leaves the switch as expected and where it stops.
Make sure that

your firewall permits Internet access from 10.1.2.2
all relevant routers have a valid route to 10.1.2.2


Thank you! You were correct, the routing was not the issue. There was a missing NAT rule required.
